# Javascript Promise.all to increse the speed of this function

Tags: javascript, promise

```
await write("video_transmitter.transmitter_assignment", "interface_command", "network_interfaces.ports[0].virtual_interfaces[0]");


var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
 await dispatch_change_request("video_transmitter.transmitter_assignment", "create_transmitter", "Click");
}

var number = 2;

var MC_Adresses_Red = []

var MC_Adresses_Blue = []

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
MC_Adresses_Red[i] = "239.1"+number+".11."+(i+1)+":"+(10000+(i+1));
MC_Adresses_Blue[i] = "239.2"+number+".11."+(i+1)+":"+(20000+(i+1));
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"]", "transport_format_command", "ST2110_GPM");
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].constraints", "max_bandwidth_command", "b3_0Gb");
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].constraints", "standard_command", null);
await dispatch_change_request("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"]", "add_new_output", "Click");
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].output_port[0]", "interface_command", "network_interfaces.ports[0].virtual_interfaces[0]");
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].output_port[1]", "interface_command", "network_interfaces.ports[1].virtual_interfaces[0]");
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].output_port[0]", "mc_address_command",MC_Adresses_Red[i]);
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"].output_port[1]", "mc_address_command", MC_Adresses_Blue[i]);
await write("video_transmitter.pool["+i+"]", "active_command", true);
}
```

This is an example of the code i am writing. I wuld like to increase the speed of this code whilst still maintaining the awaits since they are crucially important. I hear you can use promise.all but am not sure how t do this any assistance is appreciated

Comment: Promise.all will run your write in parallel, not sure that you can safely change the order of execution in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Something arround those line will partialy parallelise the execution.

`Promise.all` allows you to await a parallel array of pending promises.

so here i arbitrarly batched all your writes, but then we lost the safety of runing them in sequence.
So you should parallelise what is safe to, and await when you need to unsure you can move on to the next step.

```
var i
await Promise.all([
    write(
        'video_transmitter.transmitter_assignment',
        'interface_command',
        'network_interfaces.ports[0].virtual_interfaces[0]',
    ),
    ...Array(20)
        .fill()
        .map(() =>
            dispatch_change_request(
                'video_transmitter.transmitter_assignment',
                'create_transmitter',
                'Click',
            ),
        ),
])

var number = 2

var MC_Adresses_Red = []

var MC_Adresses_Blue = []

var i
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    MC_Adresses_Red[i] =
        '239.1' + number + '.11.' + (i + 1) + ':' + (10000 + (i + 1))
    MC_Adresses_Blue[i] =
        '239.2' + number + '.11.' + (i + 1) + ':' + (20000 + (i + 1))
}

var i
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    await Promise.all([
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + ']',
            'transport_format_command',
            'ST2110_GPM',
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].constraints',
            'max_bandwidth_command',
            'b3_0Gb',
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].constraints',
            'standard_command',
            null,
        ),
        dispatch_change_request(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + ']',
            'add_new_output',
            'Click',
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].output_port[0]',
            'interface_command',
            'network_interfaces.ports[0].virtual_interfaces[0]',
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].output_port[1]',
            'interface_command',
            'network_interfaces.ports[1].virtual_interfaces[0]',
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].output_port[0]',
            'mc_address_command',
            MC_Adresses_Red[i],
        ),
        write(
            'video_transmitter.pool[' + i + '].output_port[1]',
            'mc_address_command',
            MC_Adresses_Blue[i],
        ),
        write('video_transmitter.pool[' + i + ']', 'active_command', true),
    ])
}
```